# How to use the CSS pseudo element :before in multiple classes of same element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to display the letters of my logo text in different colors, but using `span` is very rough and using JavaScript slows the page loading time. So I tried to use the CSS pseudo element `:before`, using multiple classes of same element but it’s not working. It shows only the letter of last class, that is `letter4`. Here is the code:

```
.letter1:before {
    content:"Z";
    color:red;
}
.letter2:before {
    content:"O";
    color:green;
}
.letter3:before {
    content:"N";
    color:blue;
}
.letter4:before {
    content:"E";
    color:purple;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<span class='letter1 letter2 letter3 letter4'> </span>
```

How do I make it work?

Comment: That is because you can only have one `:before` per element. The last one just overrides the previous one.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for help on formatting your posts correctly.

Comment: You should separate like this http://jsfiddle.net/clink/DBrg5/

Comment: I wish I could use `::before(2)`. Maybe in CSS4.

Comment: _“I want to display the letters of my logo text in different colors[…] So I tried to use the CSS pseudo element :before”_ – so when viewed without CSS, your page would have no logo displayed at all … this can’t really be what you want?

Comment: I'd prefer: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/7UjgL/1/

Comment: @Hashem Qolami: Considering it was [proposed here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/#inserting0) but then abandoned, I doubt there'll even be a level 4 for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are SIR

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7UjgL/

**the style:**

```
.letter{
 width:40px;
 height:20px;
position:relative;  
letter-spacing: 26px;
}

.letter:first-letter{
color:red; 
}

.letter:before,.letter:after{
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
}
.letter:before{
    content: 'o';
    color: green;
    left: 11px;
}

.letter:after{
    content:'n';
    color:blue;
    left: 22px;
}
```

**the markup:**

```
<div class=letter>ze</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use separate span elements for it because it will be more readable in the long run.

CSS:

```
.letter1{color:red;}
.letter2{color:green;}
.letter3{color:blue;}
.letter4{color:purple;}
```

HTML:

```
<span class='letter1'>Z</span>
<span class='letter2'>O</span>
<span class='letter3'>N</span>
<span class='letter4'>E</span>
```

Comment: The code which you wrote is already used by me and i don't want this. Is doing this with css :before not possible ?

Comment: @robinton: It's not possible. In CSS2.1, each element can only have a single `:before` pseudo-element at a time.

Comment: Yes it is not possible because :before works on HTML elements not separate letters and each of them gets overwritten. @putvande already mentioned that.